# Should the norm of samples from an untrained denoising diffusion probabilistic model scale with number of diffusion steps?

Tags: diffusion-models, probabilistic-machine-learning

I have implemented a diffusion probabilistic model for the first time, and I am finding some of the model behavior undesirable, but I am not sure if it is normal or the result of an incorrect implementation.

Specifically, when I draw samples from an untrained reverse diffusion process with 20 denoising steps (by sampling from a standard normal distribution and passing the sample sequentially through the denoising kernel), I find that the elements of my final denoised samples have an average absolute value of around 400 (this number increases into the 1000s if I reverse diffuse for more steps). My training data is more like order 1 magnitude (although I am training the model to predict the noise not the noiseless training data), and so this seems problematic for efficiently training a model to me.

Even though the behaviour seems undesirable, it also seems expected from the math. For example, $x_t = \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}x_0 + \sqrt{(1-\bar{\alpha}_t)}\epsilon$, and so $x_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}}(x_t - \sqrt{(1-\bar{\alpha}_t)}\epsilon)$, where $x_0$ is the end result of denoising, $\bar{\alpha}_t = \prod_{t=1}^{T}\alpha_t$, $\alpha_t = 1 - \beta_t$, and I am using a cosine noise schedule for the betas (see code at the bottom). Therefore, $x_0$ scales with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}}$, which is equal to 406 when the number of diffusion steps (and $t$) is 20 and equal to 20291 when the number of diffusion steps (and $t$) is 1000.

Is this behavior normal? It seems problematic for efficiently training a model.

```
def cosine_beta_schedule(T, s = 0.008):
    """
    cosine schedule as proposed in https://proceedings.mlr.press/v139/nichol21a/nichol21a.pdf
    """
    t = np.linspace(0, T, T + 1)
    alphas_cumprod = np.cos((t / T + s) / (1 + s) * np.pi / 2) ** 2
    alphas_cumprod = alphas_cumprod / alphas_cumprod[0]
    betas = 1 - (alphas_cumprod[1:] / alphas_cumprod[:-1])
    betas_clipped = np.clip(betas, a_min = 0, a_max = 0.999)
    return betas_clipped

import numpy as np
n_diffusion_steps = 20
betas = cosine_beta_schedule(n_diffusion_steps)
alphas = 1. - betas
alphas_cumprod = np.cumprod(alphas)
```